# edit and Retag option not visible in question asked by peer even after having permissions

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I just went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937334/issue-with-html-module-after-uopgradation-from-dnn-4-9-5-to-6-1-2) question on SO and i found that it can be retagged and edited but even after having edit permissions, there are no edit or retag options available to me  for this question while in other questions i can see edit and retag options. may i know why it was so is there a limit on edits per day or so.

Here is snap i attached 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was already a suggested edit on the question by another user, which has now been rejected. You should be able to edit/retag it again. A post can only have one pending suggested edit at a time.

Comment: that simply means my edits can not be queued. i would wonder if i know why this behavior implemented for any post

Comment: If a second user attempts to edit it, any edits made by the first user would be lost, which may have been good edits. Thus, the pending edit has to be approved or rejected before further edits can be made, even for a user with full edit privileges (as choosing to improve the edit automatically approves it).

Comment: thanks @animuson i just edited it again :)